# Loading data in rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have a large database I need to populate with data before initially running the application. Is it best to do this in an external rake task or inside migrations?

Sincerely,
Tyler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `db/seeds.rb` is designed for this purpose. It should have been generated automatically when you created the Rails project. It has a comment at the top that explains how to use it:

```
# This file should contain all the record creation needed to seed the database with its default values.
# The data can then be loaded with the rake db:seed (or created alongside the db with db:setup).
#
# Examples:
#   
#   cities = City.create([{ :name => 'Chicago' }, { :name => 'Copenhagen' }])
#   Major.create(:name => 'Daley', :city => cities.first)
```

After you've populated it, use `rake db:seed` to populate the database with the seed data.

Comment: I think this file only exists from Rails 3 onward. But if you want to use it earlier, there shouldn't be a problem with just making the file and adding the rake task yourself.

Comment: Not true. `[~/Code/rails] rails --version
Rails 2.3.5
[~/Code/rails] rails seeds
      create  ...
      create  db/seeds.rb`